# How to write axioms in Z3 Java API?

Tags: java, z3, axiom

In Z3 api, FuncDecl has a DeclKind() to indicates if it is a rewrite rule. But how to create a rewrite rule in Z3 java API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. 
Are you referring to `Z3_OP_PR_REWRITE`?
If that is the case, this is the declaration kind used to annotate rewrite rule proof steps in Z3 proofs. It corresponds to the rewrite step described in [this article](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/iwil08.pdf) (Section 3.2).
We should not confuse this declaration kind with user defined rewrite rules.

Comment: As Leo said, custom rewrite rules are not supported directly. However, it is fairly simple to implement a specific rewriter inside of Z3 as a tactic, or from the outside using the Expr.update() function. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236450/substituting-function-symbols-in-z3-formulas where Leo explains how to do that in Python.